# When Should I use ? "nullable" with reference type in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I was wondering that should I use ? with reference type like class or string. I understood ? with value type like int?. Int without ? store default so if use ? then it can store null also.
However reference type can has null value then when we should use ? with them.

I read the documentation also but still confusion.

[nullable reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

For Example

```
public class Foo
{
  public int id;
  public string name;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Something like that
      // get id if name is pradeep
      // GetId(foo1,"pradeep");
   }

   public int GetId(Foo? foo , string? name)
   {
      // somelogic
   }
}
```

Asking this question to understand this concept.

Comment: You should look around, see what people think about null handling. It's a big topic. Now you can enable different null-state analyzers that aim to minimize the chance of *unexpected* failures caused by null references / values. It's also harder to ignore such scenarios. You have these analyzers working while designing your code (*prevention is better than cure* is also a big topic)

Comment: I don't understand that why I got focused flags. My question totally focus on one problem that is ? with reference type in c#. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 8 you can use nullable references. This allows you to be able to specify when a class can be null and also when it should not be null. You can configure your project so that the compiler will fail a build if it recognises a class that you’ve specified as non nullable that could actually be null.

It came after some statistic that said around 75% of all exceptions in C# are null reference exceptions and it causes your code to be littered with “if != null” statements.

Personally, I also think it makes you think more about the code you write.

In the example you’ve specified for instance, both arguments could throw null exceptions so you should check them before acting on them. If these weren’t specified as nullable, you could skip these checks

Comment: I understood at some level but now i have another question how can I specific a particular class nullable or non nullable in c# 8.0.?

Comment: You need to enable nullability in the project settings. If you want it to be nullable, use the question mark after the type e.g. string? If not, just specify the type as normal e.g. string.

Comment: so you mean if i use Foo? foo1 then it is nullable otherwise it will not nullable. 

if it look like that getid(Foo foo1,string? name) and pass null for foo1 then complier give error.

Comment: Correct, it won’t compile as long as you specify the “WarningsAsErrors” flag in the csproj for the specific compiler codes. If you don’t have that set then it will just be a build warning

Comment: Once you turn on nullability in the project settings, all reference types you put in code  are assumed to be not be null unless you put a `?` on them.  That means if you were declare a member property like say `public string Name { get; set; }` but never initialized it, the compiler would complain.  *That's good*.  If you wanted this property to be allowed to null you would be forced to declare it with a `?`, like `public string? Name { get; set; }`.  The same goes for parameters.  There are even attributes you can put on out params to help with this, such as the `[MayBeNullWhen]` attribute